# Is it acceptable to ask a WordPress development question here AND on WP SE?

Tags: discussion, scope, cross-posting, site-crossover

I know that WordPress SE exists. I am a member and, well, I have more than a few issues with that one SE. I'm trying to learn a whole new skill set (developing within WordPress) and I am starting to seriously wish I was posting here.

Is cross-posting coding with WordPress questions here acceptable? If so, should I link to the question I have cross-posted? If not, I understand that coding questions (which they almost all are) remain on-topic here so can I migrate my questions, should I delete the some and repost?

I'd appreciate some guidance.

Comment: As in the answer to the duplicate - cross site posting duplicate questions is not allowed and one will end up being deleted. Choosing a site to post on is a personal thing. There's pros and cons to going to the more specialised site with less traffic or to staying on SO - with her massive traffic, but broader user base.

Comment: Do not delete your posts and repost them if they have answers. We don't migrate old posts. Being on topic on one site doesn't preclude it being on topic for another site, which means migration is not necessarily a suitable option.